# How does the exponential map factor over Lie Groups?

Tags: complex-numbers, lie-groups

Consider the [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)) from $(\mathbb{C}, +) \to (\mathbb{C}, \times)$; i.e. , the complex numbers with group operation addition to the complex numbers with group operation multiplication.

We have that $(\mathbb{C}, +) \cong (\mathbb{R}, +) \oplus (\mathbb{R}, +)$; i.e. ,
$$(a,b) \in \mathbb{C} + (c,d) \in \mathbb{C} = ( (a+b) \in \mathbb{R}, (c+d) \in \mathbb{R}).$$

Next note that for complex multiplication,
$$(a,b) \times (c,d) = (ac-bd, ad+bc)$$
$$(a+bi) \times (c+di) = ac-bd + i (ad + bc)$$
$$(a+bi) \times (c+di) = A\times  (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$$
Where $A$ is the norm $A= \sqrt{ (ac-bd)^2 + (ad + bc)^2}$ and $\theta$ is the appropriate angle.

Note that $A$ is a bi-linear form. That is, $A=f(z_1, z_2),$ where $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C},$ with
$$nA =f(n \times z_1, z_2) = f(z_1, n\times z_2)$$
for $n \in \mathbb{R}.$

So, "non-rigorously" $(\mathbb{C}, \times) \cong (\mathbb{R}, \times) \otimes (\mathbb{R}, \text{rotation}).$

We postulate that the natural action of the exponential map would "distribute over":
$$(\mathbb{C}, +) \overset{\text{exp}}{\to} (\mathbb{C}, \times)$$
$$(\mathbb{R}, +) \oplus (\mathbb{R}, +) \overset{\text{exp}}{\to} (\mathbb{R}, \times) \otimes (\mathbb{R}, \text{rotation})$$
$$ [(\mathbb{R}, +) \overset{\text{exp}}{\to} (\mathbb{R}, \times)] \otimes [(\mathbb{R}, +) \overset{\text{exp}}{\to} (\mathbb{R}, \text{rotation})]$$

Or, in other words,
$$e^{a+bi} = e^a \times e^{bi}$$ where $e^{bi}$ is given by a rotation and $e^a$ just multiplies the norm of the complex number.

My question is: how can this be made rigorous? Is this way of looking at it merely intuitive, or can it can defined and generalized?

Comment: What is your definition of $e^z$ where $z$ is in ${\mathbb C}$? Do you use infinite series, or the product formula or analytic continuation of inverse to the complex logarithm...? Depending on this, you will get a different proof of the identity $e^{z+w}= e^z e^w$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm not really defining it at this point, but I am assuming that because complex multiplication is commutative, the exponential map has that property in general. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)#Elementary_properties_of_the_exponential

Answer (score 1):

This observation generalizes, and your non-rigorous isomorphism can be made rigorous.

In general, if $G = G_1 \times G_2$ is a Lie group and the Lie algebras of $G$, $G_1$, and $G_2$ are respectively $\mathfrak{g}$, $\mathfrak{g}_1$, and $\mathfrak{g}_2$, then the exponential map $\mathfrak{g} \to G$ is the product of the exponential maps $\mathfrak{g}_1 \to G_1 \times \{1\}$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2 \to \{1\} \times G_2$.

Your non-rigorous isomorphism can be perfectly rigorous if only you restrict to the positive reals and make sure that you kill rotation by $2\pi$:
$$
\mathbb{R}_{> 0} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}^\times
$$
$(r, \theta) \mapsto r\exp(2 \pi i \theta)$ is an isomorphism of Lie groups.